# Need to await tasks after ITransaction.Execute in StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

The example given for transactions on StackExchange.Redis ([source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Transactions.md)) is:

```
var newId = CreateNewId();
var tran = db.CreateTransaction();
tran.AddCondition(Condition.HashNotExists(custKey, "UniqueID"));
tran.HashSetAsync(custKey, "UniqueID", newId);
bool committed = tran.Execute();
// ^^^ if true: it was applied; if false: it was rolled back
```

Is there a need to await the task returned by the `HashSetAsync` call? The documentation states that "the result of each operation will not be known until after `Execute` (or `ExecuteAsync`) has completed". If the operation does not return any data, is it guaranteed to always be a completed task as soon as `Execute` returns, and therefore does not need to be awaited, or might there be circumstances where the operation should be awaited too? Namely, is the below superfluous?

```
var hashSetTask = tran.HashSetAsync(custKey, "UniqueID", newId);
bool committed = tran.Execute();
if (committed)
    await hashSetTask;
```